# Visual Studio linker error if function's argument constness is different in definition and declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

This code is valid:

```
// .h
void foo(int);
// .cpp
void foo(int const){} // note `const` argument
```

Even more it's considered a good practice and clang sanitizer reports about `const` in definition.

But this function produces linker error `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol` in vs2017:

```
// .h
bool check_required_device_extensions(VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice, std::vector<char const *> const & requiredExtensions);
// .cpp
using namespace std;
bool check_required_device_extensions(VkPhysicalDevice const physicalDevice, vector<char const *> const & requiredExtensions){}
```

Here's another example:

```
// .h
VkInstanceCreateInfo get_instance_create_info(std::vector<char const *> const * extensions, std::vector<char const *> const * layers);
// .cpp
VkInstanceCreateInfo get_instance_create_info(std::vector<char const *> const * const extensions, std::vector<char const *> const * const layers)
```

`gcc` compiles it without a problem.

What's strange is that this function works:

```
// .h
MaybeSurfaceFormat get_device_surface_format(VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice, VkSurfaceKHR surface);
// .cpp
MaybeSurfaceFormat get_device_surface_format(VkPhysicalDevice const physicalDevice, VkSurfaceKHR const surface){}
```

Why? Is there a special linker flag or another workaround?

Update - minimal example.

```
// a.h
#pragma once
void foo(int);
void bar(int*); // #1 - add const to fix the error

// foobar.cpp
// #2 - or include a.h to fix the error
void foo(int const){}
void bar(int* const){}

// main.cpp
#include "a.h"
int main()
{
    foo(0); // ok
    bar(nullptr); // error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

    return 0;
}
```

Win10, vs2017 Version 15.6.4 (and earlier)

Comment: Try taking out `using namespace std;`

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is the same.

Comment: I suspect it's because the first function has a reference parameter, so it does name mangling different.

Comment: It looks like a VS bug to me.

Comment: @Barmar This relates to functions without reference parameters as well. I updated the question with an example.

Comment: What are `VkPhysicalDevice` and `VkSurfaceKHR`? Maybe the issue is POD vs non-POD types. Regardless, it still looks like a VS bug.

Comment: Works for me with VS 2017.  Please provide a complete, minimal, self-contained example, indicate the tool versions, and show the exact diagnostics issued by the tool.

Comment: Added a complete, minimal, self-contained example.

Comment: It is an inevitable consequence of the way MSVC++ mangles C++ identifiers, cv qualifiers are included.  I suppose you can call it a bug but that's rather academic, the language spec doesn't dictate mangling and they are not going to change it.  The workaround is simple of course, fix the .h file.

Comment: @HansPassant If you make an answer I'll accept it.